# Capturing Group in R

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I have then following pattern `Set(?:Value)?` in R as follows:

```
grepl('Set(?:Value)?', 'Set(Value)', perl=T)
```

this pattern is macthed by

```
1- Set
2- Set Value
3- Set(Value)
```

But I want to match only for two first cases and for for third case. Can anybody help me?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps something like `grepl("Set($|[^\\(]Value)", strings)`.

Comment: Or may try `grepl('^Set(?![(]+)(?:Value)?', v1, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: You could try `Set(?:\\(Value\\))?$`

Comment: Thanks. what is the meaning of ] after (?

Comment: There is no `]` after `(?`. See the post below with all descriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```r
grepl('^Set(?:\\s+Value)?$', x)
grepl('\\bSet(?!\\(Value\\))(?:\\s+Value)?\\b', x, perl=TRUE)
```

See [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/kIilua/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/kIilua/2/).

*Details*:

- `^Set(?:\\s+Value)?$` - start of string, `Set`, an optional sequence of one or more whitespaces (`\s+`) and a `Value` and then end of string
- `\bSet(?!\(Value\))(?:\s+Value)?\b`:

  - `\b` - word boundary
  - `Set` - `Set` string
  - `(?!\(Value\))` -  no `(Value)` string allowed at this very location
  - `(?:\s+Value)?` - an optional sequence of one or more whitespaces (`\s+`) and a `Value`
  - `\b` - word boundary

See an [R demo](https://ideone.com/ldLmiZ):

```r
x <- c("Set", "Set Value", "Set(Value)")
grep('^Set(?:\\s+Value)?$', x, value=TRUE)
## => [1] "Set"       "Set Value"
grep('\\bSet(?!\\(Value\\))(?:\\s+Value)?\\b', x, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE)
## => [1] "Set"       "Set Value"
```